# Histogram calculation for rotation invariant local binary pattern in opencv c++

Tags: c++, opencv, histogram, opencv3.0, lbph-algorithm

I have been working on a opencv project that requires calculation of histogram for rotation invariant local binary pattern.I checked github and bytefish git repos but cant find what i am looking for.

Exactly what i want to say is that once i find the lbp image of any video frame or image, how to make it rotation invariant lbp and find its histogram as texture feature that can be further used for training or classification.

Can someone tell me how to exactly find the histogram for rotation invariant LBP and histogram for uniform rotation invariant LBP in opencv c++.

Thankyou!